# Proof that compact sets are closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am wondering if my following proof is sound. I know we can also show this by showing that the complement of K is open.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and suppose that $K\subset X$ is compact. We want to show that $K$ contains its limit points.

Since $K$ is compact, every open cover has a finite subcover. So, $\forall r > 0,\ \{W_k\}_{k\in K}$ has a finite subcover where $W_k = N_r(k)$. So, $\forall r>0,$ there is a finite subcover $\{W_{k_i}\}_{i=1}^{n_r}$ for $n_r\in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $x$ be a limit point of $K$ and let $r>0$. Then $\exists y_r\in N_r(x)$ such that $y_r\in K$. So, $\exists i\in \{1,\ldots, n_r\}$ such that $y_r\in N_r(k_i)$. Let $r^* = \max\limits_{j\in \{1\ldots, n_r\}} d(k_i,k_j)$. Then for any $k\in K, k\in N_{r^* +2r} (k_i)$ (i.e. $K$ is bounded).

Then $d(x,k_i) \leq d(x,y_r) + d(y_r, k_i) < r + r = 2r$. Hence, $x\in N_{2r}(k_i)$ and thus $x\in N_{r^*+2r}(k_i)$ for any $n_r\in \mathbb{N}$ (including $n_r =1$). Therefore, $x\in K\implies K$ is closed.

Comment: What is $N_r(k)$?

Comment: Why "therefore $x \in K$"? On what property is this based?

Comment: You can actually soften the requirement from $X $ being metric to it being Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to show that $x \notin K$ implies that $x$ is not a limit point of $K$:

Let $x \notin K$ be given. Then for every $k \in K$ we have an $r_k >0$ so that $x \notin N_{r_k}(k)$. Then $\{N_{r_k)}(k)\mid k \in K\}$ is an open cover of $K$ so has a finite subcover $\{N_{r_{k_1}}(k_1),\ldots, N_{r_{k_n}}(k_n)\}$. But then define $r = \min(r_{k_i}: i =1\ldots n)$ and note that $B(x,r) \cap K = \emptyset$ so that $x$ is indeed not a limit point of $K$.

Comment: But it's not necessarily true that $B(x,r)\cap K=\emptyset$ since r is just the min for finitely many k. I see why my proof does not follow though.

Comment: @N.C. It’d true though. And I don’t see why you conclude $x \in K$ in your proof attempt.